# Android: BitmapFactory decode insane slow

Tags: android, bitmap

I intent to program a little gallery application.
So I have a gridview with images, and the images that are displayed are stored
on the local device.
What I got is a Class ImageLoader that loads all images in a specific path in a background thread (AsyncTask) and stores them in a List bitmaps, where ImageItem is a pojo class with an image and a String.

The decoding of Bitmapfactory is very very slow (takes 10mins for 600 images).
How can I improve the following code to speed loading up? 
Maybe I need to decode only a scaled instance of the image?

```
private Bitmap getThumbnail(File f, int THUMBNAIL_SIZE) {
    BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    onlyBoundsOptions.inDither = false;                              //optional
    onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;  //optional
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), onlyBoundsOptions);
    if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1) || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1)) {
        return null;
    }

    int originalSize = (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight > onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth) ? onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight :
            onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;

    double ratio = (originalSize > THUMBNAIL_SIZE) ? (originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE) : 1.0;

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
    bitmapOptions.inDither = false;//optional
    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
}

private static int getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(double ratio) {
    int k = Integer.highestOneBit((int) Math.floor(ratio));
    if (k == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return k;
    }
}
```

I am using a thumbnail size of 300.

Comment: try universal image loader and dont decode all the 600 bitmaps only decode bitmaps that are visible to the user uil has a sample gridveiw example too that you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you. You shouldn't load all 600 images at once. You should only load the images that are currently within view of the grid view or list view or whatever you are using.

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/09/01/faster-loading-images-gridviews-listviews-android-menory-caching-complete-implemenation-sample-code/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @BionicSheep for your target-aimed solution.
The sample code on the link brought me to what I was looking for.
However, that code contains some suspect pieces (e.g. it is never written anything into cache). But I finally got it to work smoothly. When I am finished fixing bugs, I'll upload my modified code below.

Comment: Hi user3080611, be aware that answers are intended soley for answers. If you want to comment on an answer their is a comment field below if for that purpose

Comment: Hi, I only used the answer option becase i am going to post my source code in there. This should then rather be an answer/ solution to my question than a comment on your answer. I guess users who are looking for a similar solution can better find the answer this way.

Comment: Don't worry, the answer box isn't going away